# Dynamically retrieve attribute-value pairs of Request.RequestUri.Query?

Tags: c#, http, url, asp.net-web-api

I have the felling I'm rewriting something that must exist. Is there a better way to get and split all parameters of a http query.

I have this query

```
http://localhost:59289/api/Company/Example/Sequence/01234567890128/NextRange?Quantity=5000&Order=O1234
```

To keep things simple let's say I want to save these 2 parameters as metadata in a JSON string. Parameters can be others. The list of parameters is dynamic. I can let the user choose what he want to pass as parameters, the system will save them as metadata in JSON in my database.

In Immediate Window on Visual studio I can test this:

```
Request.RequestUri.Query
"?Quantity=5000&Order=O1234"
```

Request.RequestUri.Query is a string. I can then split it by "&" and create a dictionary of string then serialize it as JSON. But I'm surprised I have to split this by myself. Is there a better way to query all parameters keys them request all values?

I checked this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL

Solution 1 ----------

I already tried this

```
var query = @"?Quantity=5000&Order=O1234";
var p = query
    .TrimStart('?')
    .Split('&')
    .Select(y => y.Split('='))
    .SelectMany(y => new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { y[0], y[1] }
    });
```

That is my solution manually. I just get an exception in case my string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Found:

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();